# I get "Failed - Network error" when exporting database from phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp

I always find that error every time I export a database from [phpMyAdmin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpMyAdmin) using [XAMPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP). This is what it looks like, but, if I download another file from YouTube, or [Pinterest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinterest), or any other site, then there will not be any problem.

I ask my university friends, and most of them don't have the solution, because most of them don't have a problem like that.

Comment: It could be due to exporting a large sets of data. You trying to do that?

Comment: Some tipps when exporting:
1) If you try to export the whole database and it fails, try to export single tables only.
2) disable foreign key checks
3) if it still doesn't work, update your php.ini so you can export larger files
4) if nothing works, try to export via commandline

Comment: How big is the database you're trying to export? Are there any hints in the MySQL or Apache error logs? Can you try with a different browser? Do you have any kind of firewall or IPS on your network?

Answer (score 13):

Downgrading to an older PHP version solves this problem. phpMyAdmin 5.1.3 currently has issues with PHP 8.1. So, I downgraded to 7.4.28.

Comment: It's actually only a problem with PHP 8.0.17 and 8.1.4 specifically. I downgraded to 8.1.3 and was back up and running.

Comment: I confirm the issue with php 8.0.17

Comment: also with PMA 5.1.1 + PHP 8.0.17

Comment: Also with PMA 5.1.1 and PHP 8.0.18, instead with PHP 7.4.29 it works

Comment: Downgrading php version is not a feasible method ,, if our project is running with 8. or greater  how its possible ?

Comment: With PMA 5.1.3 and PHP version 8.1.5, the issue remains!

Comment: I had 8.1.4. Upgrading to 8.1.6 helped.

Comment: How do I downgrade PHP My Admin when I am using XAMPP?

Comment: PMA 5.1.3 PHP: 8.0.20 same problem using laragon

Comment: If you upgrade to PHP 8.1.6, the issue will be resolved. Otherwise downgrade to PHP 7.4.

Answer (score 8):

There had been a bug or change with how PHP handles setting headers which had affected phpMyAdmin, but it has been worked around by phpMyAdmin starting with releases 5.1.4 and 5.2.0 which were published on 2022-05-10.

There's a [phpMyAdmin bug report](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/17445) with quite a bit of discussion if you want the back history on this.

Edit: Updated the answer because the fix has been released.

Comment: I have used phpMyAdmin 5.1.3 with php8.1 on XAMPP.
I reinstalled the same version. Nothing happened.
So, I have installed "phpMyAdmin 5.2+snapshot" after that. It all worked.
Just copy the new phpMyAdmin folder over the old one. Replace all same files.
Thank you, Isaac!

Answer (score 0):

**phpMyAdmin export network error in PHP 8.1.4**

When I tried to export a test database as SQL, it gave me an error file as *test.sql*.

I renamed it as .html and copied it to the *pma* folder and accessed via *localhost/phpmyadmin/test.html*.

It shows

```
index.php: Missing parameter: what
index.php: Missing parameter: export_type
```

[See error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRt8b.png)

phpMyAdmin 5.1.3 has an issue with PHP 8.1.4.

Downgrading to older a PHP version solves this problem. I downgraded to 8.0.18. It works for me.

Comment: There is a Workaround!!!
simlpy use the option: show Output as Text. Then Copy Paste the Output to a Textfile ans save ist.