# sql is not exporting from phpmyadmin

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

[This is the Error when i try to export my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oialt.png)

Even When i try to export in any other format it is not exporting the sql

Comment: Your question looks a lot like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71615310/failed-network-error-when-i-exporting-from-phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

this is also an answer to [Failed - Network error when i exporting from phpmyadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71615310/failed-network-error-when-i-exporting-from-phpmyadmin?noredirect=1&lq=1)

upgrading my phpMyAdmin version from v5.1.3 to v5.2.0 solved this

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31940983)