# Why I Can't export database in phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin

I Have a laravel project. And using phpmyadmin for my database. And When I Export The Database, It Can't to be downloaded. My Connection Is Stable.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLcvB.png)

Comment: question: Are u using php 8?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71615310/i-get-failed-network-error-when-exporting-database-from-phpmyadmin

Answer (score -1):

## Export database from CMD Xampp

1. Open CMD
2. `cd C:\xampp\mysql\bin`   Default Route
3. `mysqldump -u root -p db_name > C:\xampp\db_name_dump.sql`
4. Enter password (Default blank)
5. Wait while exporting
6. You can find the file in the directory `C:\xampp` with the name from step 3

### Use this in your case

`mysqldump -u root -p rumahbaca > C:\xampp\rumahbaca_dump.sql`

### I advise you to update phpmyadmin I share a guide:

[Guide](https://ostraining.com/blog/coding/update-phpmyadmin/)

[Official phpmyadmin 5.2.0](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/news/2022/5/10/phpmyadmin-520-released/)